# EclipseFP for Haskell not working

Tags: eclipse, haskell, functional-programming

I've installed the EclipseFP plugin so I can work with Haskell in Eclipse. I am running Eclipse on my Mac. I have the most recent JRE, found somewhere that that may be the issue. The plugin is not in Windows --> Open Perspective --> Other which is where is should be. I am using Eclipse Luna.

I am relatively new and would like to learn haskell

Comment: Also you should know that  [EcliseFP is no longer supported.](http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.in/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html)

Comment: I can't help you with EclipseFP. If you are beginning to learn Haskell, however, I sense it will only be an extra complication. Just start coding on your favourite text editor (vim, Emacs, or anything else with sensible features for writing code) while keeping GHCi open so that you can test things quickly.

Comment: Also if you really want a help with `EclipseFP`, you should talk with maintainer / author or create an issue in [github](https://github.com/JPMoresmau/eclipsefp).

Comment: Just install the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/downloads) and read [Haskell in 5 Steps](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps) for a quick intro on using ghci and compiling programs.